# Search with AJAX working, good! How to display results correctly?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, search, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I followed [this tutorial](http://railscasts.com/episodes/240-search-sort-paginate-with-ajax?view=asciicast) to add AJAX to my Rails3.1 search box(everything works fine). This search box in in a side bar, and I want to display the results in the main column. The problem I encounter is that I don't know how to this properly.

Before AJAX I had a search.html.haml with the code to display the results. However, if I add the render partial call here nothing get displayed(I guess is because the search.html.haml does not get called)

search.html.haml

```
=@events.count
#search=render 'search'
```

On the other hand, if I place the render partial call in the application.html.haml. It does display the results, but underneath the actual content of the main column.

application.html.haml

```
     #central
        %p#notice= notice
        = yield
        #search=render 'search'
```

I guess it is a simple fix, but not sure how to do it.

Thanks in advance!!!

_search.html.haml

```
 -@events.each do |event|
   #user_block
     #user_block_pic
      = image_tag(event.pic.url(:medium), class: 'event_block_image', :alt =>'Event Picture')
      ....more stuff
```

search.js.erb

```
  $('#search').html("<%= escape_javascript( render(:partial => 'search') ) %>");
```

How can I do to get rid of what is on the main column(#central) and display the results in there?

FIXED!!!! NOW WORKING!!!! (since I have to wait hours to be allowed to post an answer I do it here)

I am not sure this is correct coding but worked for me. What I did is to get rid of the middle file search.html.haml(see above)

And now the configuration is this:

application.html.haml

```
   #central
        %p#notice= notice
        = yield
```

_search.html.haml

```
#search
 =@events.count
 -@events.each do |event|
   ...stuff
```

assets/javascript/search.js

```
 $(function(){ 
$("#search .pagination a").live("click", function(){   #this is for pagination
    $.getScript(this.href);
    return false;
});
$('#events_search').submit(function () {  #this is for the search form
    $.get(this.action, $(this).serialize(), null, 'script');
    return false;
  });
 });
```

views/events/search.js.erb

```
  $('#central').html("<%= escape_javascript( render(:partial => 'search') ) %>");
```

It works fine for me. Hope this can help others.

Thanks

Comment: *if I add the render partial call here nothing get displayed* - how do you render it? where?

Answer (score 0):

When you search method gets called from the ajax call it wants to render `search.js.erb` or haml I guess, but I don't use haml, only erb.

So then you create a `search.js.erb`, here is an example of my `search.js.erb`:

```
$("#user-browser").replaceWith("<%= escape_javascript render(:partial => 'list') %>");
$("#tabs-interval").replaceWith("<%= escape_javascript render(:partial => 'tabs-interval') %>");
```

So all my erb does is use jquery to find the div's I want to update the html in, using the rendered partials and replaces the html in them.

My partials look like so in erb:

file: `list.html.erb`:

```
<div id="user-browser">
  <span>more html stuff</span>
</div>
```

file: `tabs-interval.html.erb`:

```
<div id="tabs-interval">
  <span>more html stuff</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Just added the questions to show what I had. I replace my .html with yours .replaceWith. And that makes the results show in the main column. However, after one search, search or pagination does nor work unless I reload the page. And they were working before. weird...

Comment: I managed to get it working. Thanks for your help, it guided my to solve my problem. I post the answer in a sec.